# To determine the path of current in a complex circuit. (CAP contest question)

Tags: electric-circuits

How to determine the path of current in this diagram[image] ? Intuitively, I guess the current won't pass through wire DC...

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since real wires have some resistance,  the current will divide and follow all branches: it is a parallel system. The shortest path will have the lowest resistance.

Also see [Wheatstone bridge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge); if the resistances are properly balanced there will be no current in the diagonal wire; if the wires are uniform this will be the actual case here.

Comment: I was able to prove that current will flow in *all* wires. The prove is long though. So, Peter is correct; in general (not knowing resistances ahead of time) all branches will allow passage of current.

Comment: @Benjamin: One can pick trivial values for the wire resistances for which no current will flow in the diagonal. If your lengthy proof doesn't show that, it's flat out false.

Comment: @ CuriousOne: My lengthy proof does show that.

Comment: Plus, things that may seem trivial for a physicist may not be so for a student.